# Jquery UI datepicker with Ajax control toolkit modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to use the jquery datepicker (the ajax control toolkit one will not work for our purposes) inside of an Ajax control toolkit modalpopup extender. The jquery datepicker does not function inside the modal popup extender. It works fine on a textbox outside of the modal. Any way to use the 2 together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may that you are calling the function which associate the **JQuery** `DatePicker` control with your `TextBox` control at the **loading** of your **page** when the **Popup** container is not rendered because it is not visible.

Try to call that function on an event that occures right after the **Popup** container control is rendered.

I have a `div` and because I am using the `onmouseover` event to do it.. However, you can find a better event to implement it ..

```
<div onmouseover="AssociateJQueryDatePickerToMyTextBox();" ... > ... </div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was -- tried with a div around the textbox and it worked. Now i'll hook it into a more proper event. Issue now seems to be with the z-index. Guess my modal has a higher index than the datepicker